# For two periodic sets $A,B$, $A \cup (B + \{x\}) = \{y\} + A \cup B$ for some $y \in \Bbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A,B$ be *periodic* subsets of $\Bbb{N}$, in other words each has an associated $T \in \Bbb{N}$ such that if $x \in A$, then $x + T \in A$, always, for instance.

Let $x + A$ mean a translate of $A$, or $\{ x + a : a  \in A\}$.

Then for any $x \in \Bbb{N}$, $(x + A) \cup B = y + A \cup B$ for some $y \in \Bbb{N}$.  For instance take $A = 3\Bbb{N}$, $B = 5 \Bbb{N}$, $x = 2$.

$$
x + A = \{ 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, \dots \} \\
B = \{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, \dots \} \\
$$

It's better to see the pattern with dots:

```
........................................................(repeat)
A     : *        *        *        *        *        *        *        *
B     : *              *              *              *              *
A|B   : *        *     *  *        *  *     *        *        *     *   *
(2+A) :       *        *        *        *        *        *        *
(2+A)|B:*     *        *        *     *  *        *  *     *        *
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1
```

Seems like it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true.

Let
$$
A = 100 \mathbb N, \\ 
B = 50\mathbb N.
$$

Then

$(1 + A) \cup B$ contains numbers that differ by 49, (e.g., $1 \in 1 + A$, $50 \in B$)

while for any $x \in \mathbb  N$,

$x + (A \cup B)$ contains only numbers that differ by multiples of 50, because every number in $A \cup B$ is divisible by $50$.

Comment: What if $x$ is constrained to be in $B$?

Comment: Or under what conditions do you think it's true if ever?

Comment: Then it's an altogether different question, but still false. Consider $A = 50N - \{10\}$, $B = 50N \cup (50N + \{10\}$, and $x = 10$. Then $(x + A) \cup B = B$, but $A \cup B$ contains numbers differing by $20$, and hence so does $y + (A \cup B)$, for any $y$, and hence it cannot equal $B$.   .

Comment: As for "When is it true?", I have no idea. (And it doesn't really grab me as a problem, so I'm not going to look into it -- that's up to you!)